# How can the C function "Exp" be properly used in NASM for Linux?

Tags: c, linux, nasm, exp

I am trying to implement the C function "exp" in NASM for Linux. The function takes a double value x, and returns a double value r = e^x, where e is Euler's Number. This is my implementation:

```
extern exp

SECTION .bss

    doubleActual: resq 1
    doubleX: resq 1

SECTION .text

    main:
    ;some other code here

    ;calculate actual result
    push doubleActual ; place to store result
    push doubleX ;give the function what x is.
    call exp
    add esp, 8
```

On compile attempt, i get the following:

```
hw7_3.o: In function `termIsLess':
hw7_3.asm:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `exp'
```

This is referring to when i actually call exp, which is odd, because "extern exp" seems to work just fine. What am i doing incorrectly?

Comment: Do you link to whatever library it's defined in?

Comment: using NASM for linux, this is usually not necessary. For example, i can "extern printf" and then instantly be able to use "call printf" in my code. I assume this is unique to C functions.

Comment: My guess is you need a `-lm` to link in the cmath library.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but how would i do this? I have not needed to link with NASM before. My current compile routine is: "nasm -f elf32 name.asm" followed by "gcc -m32 name.o -o name", where name is my program's name.

Comment: You didn't need to do anything for other functions because you let GCC do the linking for you and it always links to `libc`. But it doesn't link to `libm` implicitly.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. So printf, scanf, sscanf, exit, and other c functions are declared in a more general library that is auto-linked, but "exp" is not in this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

via http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/gccintro_17.html ....

I need to do the following with gcc:

```
gcc -m32 name.o -lm -o name
```

The "-lm" tag is a shortcut to link the C math library, which is separate from the standard library.